# Replace all occurence by the match in python

Tags: python, regex, url, python-re

I want to replace all site by their equivalent html in python
I've this:

```
regex_site = "http:\/\/[^ ]*"
tempo_line = re.sub(r'http:\/\/[^ ]*',r'<a href="\1">\1</a>',line)
return tempo_line
```

But I've those errors...

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 1036, in parse_template
> addgroup(int(this[1:]), len(this) - 1)
> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/sre_parse.py", line 980, in addgroup
> raise s.error("invalid group reference %d" % index, pos)
> re.error: invalid group reference 1 at position 10

I don't understand why, could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have *group* in your pattern denoted by `(` and `)` (more precisely at least one group as you are referencing first one via `\1`). Consider following example

```
import re
txt = "something someone"
print(re.sub(r'some',r'\1\1\1',txt))  # cause error: invalid group reference 1 at position 1
print(re.sub(r'(some)',r'\1\1\1',txt))  # print: somesomesomething somesomesomeone
```

If you know that your pattern match as intended (you might use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to check that) simply enclose it in `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 0):

`Regex_site` must be initialized with closing and opening round bracket

This code snippet replaces all the URL with  tag.

```py
import re

line = "stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com github https://www.github.com"
regex_site = r"(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})"
tempo_line = re.sub(regex_site, r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', line)
print(tempo_line)
```

Output:

> stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com github https://www.github.com

Answer (score 0):

`re` uses extended regex syntax, where `\1` denotes the first group element you've put into parenthesis `(my 1st group)`

In your case, you would want to either use `\0` (your whole regex match) or put something in parenthesis - but somehow `\0` is not supported well for the whole match, so better to use `\g<0>` (repl notation)

For more info, see the doc for [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

> Backreferences, such as `\6`, are replaced with the substring matched by group 6
>
> [...]
>
> In string-type repl arguments, in addition to the character escapes and backreferences described above, `\g<name>` will use the substring matched by the group named name. [...] `\g<number>` uses the corresponding group number; `\g<2>` is therefore equivalent to `\2`, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as `\g<2>0`. `\20` would be interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a reference to group 2 followed by the literal character `'0'`. The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

```py
import re
regex_site = r"https?:\/\/[^ ]*"
result = re.sub('(' + regex_site + ')', r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', line)
result = re.sub(regex_site, r'<a href="\g<0>">\g<0></a>', line)
```

I also added the `?` to have `s` as an optional character of your URL